# Wise for Windows: Advt and Non-Advt shortcuts

Tags: windows-installer, wise

I have 2 MSI packages exactly the same but one has advertised shortcuts and other has non-advertised shortcuts. I have a third MSI package which needs to be upgraded with the above.

Observation:
When I upgrade with the "non-advt shortcuts" package then I do not get short cuts in start menu.

When I upgrade with the "advt shortcuts" package then I do  get short cuts in start menu.

If I use DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1 in "advt shortcuts" package then I do not get short cuts in start menu.

From log file I could see that in the "advt shortcuts" package , the action "ShortcutRemove" seems to be skipped saying the latest package has overwritten the shortcut, so it cannot be removed. Hence I guess I can see the short cuts in start. But no such luck with non advt shortcut package. I assume that the shortcuts are being written and then removed. But why? I tried keeping the Remove Shortcut command in a if block like If REMOVE, then Remove Shortcut. But it did not seem to affect. Any leads would be appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shortcuts, advertised or non-advertised, are associated with components. From the MSI Log file, what is the status of the components. I suspect that this is the problem and once you figure out the component state it will reveal your problem.

Also, for your MSI, do a ICE validation to see if you are violating any component rules that can affect upgrades.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I am having trouble understanding how to execute this ICE validation. Can you please help in this as well?

Comment: I do not mind helping out but I would appreciate if you attempt a google search first. :)  

https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/package-validation-benefits-and-directions